# Break points not working on WinRT CPP File

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2017

I have a UWP C# project.I am adding a WinRT cpp project's solution to it. .CS file calls a function on cpp. I have added break points.But control is not going to cpp while running. I have tried below changes.But shows no effect

```
Rebuld the project
Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Edit and Continue
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run. Make sure the top two options ('On Run, when projects are out date' and 'On Run, when build or deployment errors occur') and in a reasonable state (NOT 'never build' or 'Launch old version').
```

Comment: Breakpoint not being hit, or cpp code is not called at all? They are two different problems

Comment: cpp code is calling. break points  are not hitting on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project property, find ***Debug*** tab, and in "Debugger type", set Application process as "Native Only".

The default for C# solution is "Managed Only" so breakpoints in cpp won't be hit.

[image: debugger type]